# How to fix sql injection in .net core for string parameters in GET methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get, query-string, sql-injection

net core application. I have many API's in my application. I ran security scan tool and I found sql injection for the below API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getdata")]
public async Task<string> GetData(string param1 = "", string param2 = "", string param3 = "")
{
  //logic
}
```

Below comment from Security scan report

```
URL         https://mywebapp/getdata/getdata? 
            param1=S+5.0145%27+AND+%271%27%3D%271&param2=T102.5.42&param3=Bulgaria
Method      GET
Parameter   param1
Attack      S 5.0-145' AND '1'='1
```

I have many other APIs but I dint get any sql injections for example,

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("mydetails/{param1}")]
public async Task<string> mydetails(string param1)
{
}
```

In this API I dint get any SQL injection comments. For the first example I have sql injection in report as shown above. Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi Llama, I am using EFCore Linq

Comment: Could you show a fuller example then, please. Is the tool you have used complaining that your website doesn't block such parameters, or is it the result of actually successfully injecting SQL? It shouldn't be possible with basic CRUD EFCore code.

Comment: yes tool is telling website doesn't block such parameters

Comment: Then I'm not sure how important that is really. If you really want something to block such requests, you would probably have to construct a middleware to detect them and perhaps have some way of determining if they look like SQL injection.

Comment: If you actually have SQL injection you need to show us that code. If it's just the tool complaining that you didn't block the query, but you are actually parameterizing, get a better tool. My full legal name is `Robert'; DROP TABLE Students --` [why should you care?](https://bobby-tables.com/) Sanitizing inputs is madness, just parameterize everything